# Setting location.href removes port number

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I am developing an application whose initial page resides at:

`https://localhost:8443/#/signin`

I want to perform a redirect from JavaScript to the following location:

`https://localhost:8443/admin`

To do this, I write code as follows:

`location.href = location.origin + '/admin';`

However, when I do perform this, the page browses to:

`https://localhost/admin`

I also tried `location.assign()` with the same result.

Why does setting `location.href` or `location.assign()` remove the port-number from the URL?

Any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: You can add "location.port"

Comment: Where do I do that? Because the moment I set `location.href`, it triggers a navigation. And the navigated page does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @[RyanNghiem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3344953/ryan-nghiem) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224863/setting-location-href-removes-port-number#comment42927740_27224863), add `location.port`:

```
location.href = location.origin + ':' + location.port + '/admin';
```

Maybe it's a good idea to check if `location.port` exists, to prevent the colon from being added without a port:

```
location.href = location.origin + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + '/admin';
```

Comment: But `location.origin` already gives me `https://localhost:8443`. Also when I tried `location.href = location.protocol + '// + location.hostname + ':' + location.port + '/admin';`, it still does not work.

Comment: Hm, so it does. `location.href = location.origin + '/admin';` actually seems to work for me...

Comment: I am testing on Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) on a Mac OSX. I tried the same on Firefox 33.1, and its the same problem.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Is there some code in your app that redirects the page on some conditions?

Comment: Hmm, looks like I have some code that is causing this behavior. Thanks for your input!